# Method of spending LTC Litecoin from a paper cold wallet?

Tags: litecoin, paper-wallet, coldstorage, sending, spending

I know mycellium has a feature for BTC where you can spend partial amounts from a Bitcoin cold paper wallet. Is there something like this for a LTC Litecoin cold paper wallet? I just want to spend a few ltc, but not sweep the entire paper wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the private key, spend part of it, send the change back to the same address, and delete the key. This would leave a lesser amount in the same paper wallet, but is generally not a good practice (address reuse).

Also, if the address has multiple inputs, you can just spend X if Y distinct inputs with exact change and that will work too.

```
litecoin-cli importprivkey 1LYourPrivateKeyThatIsWrittenOnThePaperThatYouWantToKeepForSomeReason
```

Comment: how do you send the change back to the same address with that command? or is it by default?

Comment: Just use the GUI if that's available to you. Otherwise: 1) List all the unspent inputs for your address: `litecoin-cli listunspent 1 99999999 '''["paperWALLETpublicKEY"]''` then 2) do the math and create a raw transaction sending your spend amount to wherever and the change back to you: `litecoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{ "txid" : "<txid_of_selected_block>", "vout" : <vout>}]' '{"<recipient_address>": <amount_to_send>, "<sender_address>": <amount_change>}' ` then 3) sign it and send it to the blockchain.